# How to lose focus on input-text when mouseleave is triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

My question is, how to lose focus when `mouseleave` event is triggered.
The flow is as follows:

- Click input-text;
- Write something;
- Leave the input-text (with mouse)
- Input-text looses focus, meaning if you type something it will not
  update the value inside the text-box;

```html
<input ng-mouseover="$root.gridOptionsForReportErrors.filterFocus()"
       ng-mouseleave="$root.gridOptionsForReportErrors.filterBlur()"
       ng-click="$root.gridOptionsForReportErrors.filterFocus()"
       type="text" 
       class="ui-grid-filter-input ui-grid-filter-input-0 ng-empty ng-touched" 
       ng-model="colFilter.term"
       ng-attr-placeholder="{{colFilter.placeholder || ''}}" 
       aria-label="Filter for column" 
       placeholder="">
```

In the code above `$root.gridOptionsForReportErrors.filterBlur()` function is triggered successfully in Chrome as in IE.

But the input-text remains selected in Chrome and in IE the input-text looses focus, as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one fix for this:

1. I gave an id to the input-box (the one which is posted)
   `id="inputvalerror"`
2. and in the `fliterBlur` function, I searched for this input-box element by the id and called the `blur` function

like this:

`$('#inputvalerror').blur();`